# Counting number of rows including blank rows until 2 blanks encountered

Tags: excel, vba

Currently have a macro which counts the number of rows to use as a variable. Due to new data source which has blank rows this no longer functions.

I need it to continue counting until it hits two blanks which is the end of the data source but also include the blank rows in the count.

I have a macro that counts the number of rows to provide a variable for a separate macro which uses that number for a loop function. Everything was working fine except the new data to count has blank row in between data (which must remain and included in the total row count).

I can figure out how to count non-blanks and full cells separately but can't figure out how to do it together. Any suggestions?

```
Sub num_rows(nrows As Variant)
    Dim numrows
    Dim ra As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    'get number of rows between blank cells
    Sheets("4 Gantt Overview").Activate
    Set ra = Range("b7")

    numrows = Range(ra.Address,Range(ra.Address).End(xlDown)).rows.Count
    Range(ra.Address).Select

    'establish counting loop
    For i = 1 To numrows      
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select          
    Next

    nrows = numrows        
    Range("b7").Select 
End Sub
```

For a data set of 130 rows and 2 blanks its counting only to 30 rows (the first blank position).

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: `For a data set of 130 rows and 2 blanks its counting only to 30 rows (the first blank position).` That is because you are using `xlDown` I think what you need is the last row? If yes then you may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: Is this your range? `MsgBox Sheets("4 Gantt Overview").Range("B7:B" & Sheets("4 Gantt Overview").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Address`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the following data:

[image]

If you want to find the first 2 blanks, you can use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` to fund all blanks in your range (here column A). It will turn something like the selected cells in the image. There are 6 selected areas that you can access with `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Areas`.

So if we loop through all these areas `For Each Area In .Areas` and check their row count `If Area.Rows.Count >= 2`, we can easily find the area with 2 rows (or at least 2 rows).

The amount of rows (empty or not) is then `Area.Row - AnalyzeRange.Row`

So we end up with:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestCount()
    MsgBox CountRowsUntilTwoBlanks(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))
End Sub


Function CountRowsUntilTwoBlanks(AnalyzeRange As Range) As Long
    Dim Area As Range
    For Each Area In AnalyzeRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Areas
        If Area.Rows.Count >= 2 Then 'if 2 or more then use >=2, if exactly 2 use =2
            CountRowsUntilTwoBlanks = Area.Row - AnalyzeRange.Row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Area
End Function
```

So for this example it will return `16` rows.

---

Note that if your goal is to find the last used row, which in this example would be row 20 then you could just use …

```
Dim LastRow As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

… to find the last used row in column A. Here `LastRow` returns `20`.

Comment: Perfect! With a slight rejig that got everything working again. Didn't think of the .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Areas function - Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

This this macro. It will find first cell that is blank with a following cell blank as well.

```
Sub stopAtDoubleBlank()

        Dim i As Long

        i = 2
        Do While Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Or Range("A" & i + 1) <> ""

            i = i + 1
        Loop

        MsgBox i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this too if you want:

```
Sub lastrow()
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
    Cells(1, lr).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    lr = ActiveCell.Row
End Sub
```

(go down to the very bottom and jump up to the last not empty row in A cloumn(that can be changed) also you can add something like +1 if you want an empty row at the end)

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thank you for the article!:)